npm run buildで「ERROR in node_modules/@types/jqueryui/index.d.ts(645,11): error TS1110: Type expected.」が発生する
docker build内のnpm run buildでエラーになります。
2年ほど前に開発したときはnpm run buildで正常動作していたのですが、
改めて開発環境を構築し直した際にエラーになります。
ERROR in node_modules/@types/jqueryui/index.d.ts(645,11): error TS1110: Type expected.

typescriptのバージョンを上げると改善されるサイトがあったため試したところ、エラーが1箇所だけ残りました。
しかし、このエラーだけが消すことができません。
エラーの元となっている@types/jqueryuiを消すと開発ソース内でエラーとなるため、使用しているパッケージとなります。
確認した内容
①そのまま実行
②typescriptのバージョン変更
③typescriptと依存関係のある@angular/compiler-cliのバージョン変更
このエラーを無くす方法をご教授いただけないでしょうか。
詳細は以下となります。
①そのまま実行したときのエラー内容（2年ほど前に開発したときと同じ内容）
 > [build_Hoge-front 10/10] RUN npm run build:
0.594 
0.594 > Hoge-Test@0.0.0 prebuild /usr/src/Hoge/front-end
0.594 > ts-node git.version.ts
0.594 
1.132 The command 'git describe' is successfully executed when pre-build, the result: 'v1.2.0-21-g1f056c8'
1.143 
1.143 > Hoge-Test@0.0.0 build /usr/src/Hoge/front-end
1.143 > ng build --aot --prod --base-href /priv/
1.143 
3.786                                                                                      
16.32 Date: 2024-08-29T05:29:23.872Z
16.32 Hash: 484d03de914203de8543
16.32 Time: 12534ms
16.32 chunk {scripts} scripts.015cc2de5a7b3600d66d.js (scripts) 126 kB  [rendered]
16.32 chunk {0} runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js (runtime) 1.05 kB [entry] [rendered]
16.32 chunk {1} styles.754e83ac45b0a35831cf.css (styles) 211 kB [initial] [rendered]
16.32 chunk {2} polyfills.57838466c7d879c59877.js (polyfills) 130 bytes [initial] [rendered]
16.32 chunk {3} main.9aedd4c175d67a066c0b.js (main) 128 bytes [initial] [rendered]
16.32 
16.32 
16.32 
16.32 ERROR in node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(12795,21): error TS1005: ')' expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(12795,29): error TS1131: Property or signature expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(12796,24): error TS1005: ';' expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(12797,24): error TS1005: ';' expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(12798,24): error TS1005: ';' expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(12798,59): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(12799,13): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(12799,41): error TS1005: ';' expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(12800,9): error TS1109: Expression expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(12855,25): error TS1005: ',' expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(12855,51): error TS1005: ')' expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(12855,68): error TS1005: ',' expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(12855,83): error TS1005: ',' expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(12855,93): error TS1005: ';' expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(12855,111): error TS1005: ';' expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(12855,112): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(12855,113): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(12915,12): error TS1005: ';' expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(13068,33): error TS1005: ',' expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(13069,13): error TS1109: Expression expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(13073,21): error TS1005: ')' expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(13073,38): error TS1005: ',' expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(13073,48): error TS1005: ';' expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(13073,66): error TS1005: ';' expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(13073,67): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(13074,5): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(13074,6): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(13226,33): error TS1005: ',' expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(13227,13): error TS1109: Expression expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(13231,21): error TS1005: ')' expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(13231,33): error TS1005: ';' expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(13231,51): error TS1005: ';' expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(13231,52): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(13232,5): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(13232,6): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(13363,33): error TS1005: ',' expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(13364,13): error TS1109: Expression expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(13368,21): error TS1005: ')' expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(13368,38): error TS1005: ',' expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(13368,48): error TS1005: ';' expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(13368,76): error TS1005: ';' expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(13368,77): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(13369,5): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(13369,6): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(13371,7): error TS1005: ',' expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(13371,16): error TS1005: ';' expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts(13372,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
16.32 node_modules/@types/jqueryui/index.d.ts(645,11): error TS1110: Type expected.
16.32 
16.35 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
16.35 npm ERR! errno 1
16.35 npm ERR! Hoge-Test@0.0.0 build: `ng build --aot --prod --base-href /priv/`
16.35 npm ERR! Exit status 1
16.35 npm ERR! 
16.35 npm ERR! Failed at the Hoge-Test@0.0.0 build script.
16.35 npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
16.36 
16.36 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
16.36 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2024-08-29T05_29_23_909Z-debug.log
------

 4 warnings found (use docker --debug to expand):
 - FromAsCasing: 'as' and 'FROM' keywords' casing do not match (line 3)
 - FromAsCasing: 'as' and 'FROM' keywords' casing do not match (line 18)
 - InvalidBaseImagePlatform: Base image alpine@sha256:3b3f647d2d99cac772ed64c4791e5d9b750dd5fe0b25db653ec4976f7b72837c was pulled with platform "linux/arm64", expected "linux/amd64" for current build (line 33)
 - InvalidBaseImagePlatform: Base image arm64v8/erlang@sha256:a9832017735f81c862faeb36ec84faeda2e12dbc3e2faf351eb381736f7e717b was pulled with platform "linux/arm64", expected "linux/amd64" for current build (line 18)
Hoge-Alpine.Dockerfile:12
--------------------
  10 |     RUN npm install -g npm@6.13.7
  11 |     RUN npm install ng-circle-progress@1.5.1 --save
  12 | >>> RUN npm run build
  13 |     
  14 |     # Get Arm based Docker Alpine Linux, including Erlang/OTP 20,
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm run build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

②package.jsonにあるtypescriptのバージョンを~2.7.2から~3.4.2に変えて実行したときのエラー内容
（typscriptと@angular/compiler-cliとの依存関係が合わないとのログになる）
 > [build_Hoge-front 10/10] RUN npm run build:                                                                                                                                                                         
0.628 
0.628 > Hoge-Test@0.0.0 prebuild /usr/src/Hoge/front-end
0.628 > ts-node git.version.ts
0.628 
1.287 The command 'git describe' is successfully executed when pre-build, the result: 'v1.2.0-25-g1af54fa'
1.299 
1.299 > Hoge-Test@0.0.0 build /usr/src/Hoge/front-end
1.299 > ng build --aot --prod --base-href /priv/
1.299 
2.818 
2.818 @angular/compiler-cli@6.1.10 requires typescript@'>=2.7.0 <2.8.0' but 3.2.4 was found instead.
2.818 Using this version can result in undefined behaviour and difficult to debug problems.
2.818 
2.818 Please run the following command to install a compatible version of TypeScript.
2.818 
2.818     npm install typescript@'>=2.7.0 <2.8.0'
2.818 
2.818 To disable this warning run "ng config cli.warnings.typescriptMismatch false".
2.818 
4.657                                                                                      
10.64 Date: 2024-09-10T06:27:34.880Z
10.64 Hash: c948bfde79f03a1ebd6a
10.64 Time: 5988ms
10.64 chunk {scripts} scripts.015cc2de5a7b3600d66d.js (scripts) 126 kB  [rendered]
10.64 chunk {0} runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js (runtime) 1.05 kB [entry] [rendered]
10.64 chunk {1} styles.754e83ac45b0a35831cf.css (styles) 211 kB [initial] [rendered]
10.64 chunk {2} polyfills.57838466c7d879c59877.js (polyfills) 130 bytes [initial] [rendered]
10.64 chunk {3} main.9aedd4c175d67a066c0b.js (main) 128 bytes [initial] [rendered]
10.65 
10.65 
10.65 
10.65 ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=2.7.2 and <2.10.0 but 3.2.4 was found instead.
10.68 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
10.68 npm ERR! errno 1
10.68 npm ERR! Hoge-Test@0.0.0 build: `ng build --aot --prod --base-href /priv/`
10.68 npm ERR! Exit status 1
10.68 npm ERR! 
10.68 npm ERR! Failed at the Hoge-Test@0.0.0 build script.
10.68 npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
10.69 
10.69 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
10.69 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2024-09-10T06_27_34_917Z-debug.log
------
Hoge.Dockerfile:12
--------------------
  10 |     RUN npm install -g npm@6.13.7
  11 |     RUN npm install ng-circle-progress@1.5.1 --save
  12 | >>> RUN npm run build
  13 |     
  14 |     # Get Arm based Docker Alpine Linux, including Erlang/OTP 20,
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm run build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

③@angular/compiler-cliを6.0.3から7.2.15に変更に変えて実行したときのエラー内容（今ここ）
 > [build_Hoge-front 10/10] RUN npm run build:                                                                                                                                                                         
0.887 
0.887 > Hoge-Test@0.0.0 prebuild /usr/src/Hoge/front-end
0.887 > ts-node git.version.ts
0.887 
1.604 The command 'git describe' is successfully executed when pre-build, the result: 'v1.2.0-25-g1af54fa'
1.616 
1.616 > Hoge-Test@0.0.0 build /usr/src/Hoge/front-end
1.616 > ng build --aot --prod --base-href /priv/
1.616 
5.027                                                                                      
20.10 Date: 2024-09-10T06:30:21.762Z
20.10 Hash: 103d6cd95470bbd617e9
20.10 Time: 15077ms
20.10 chunk {scripts} scripts.015cc2de5a7b3600d66d.js (scripts) 126 kB  [rendered]
20.10 chunk {0} runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js (runtime) 1.05 kB [entry] [rendered]
20.10 chunk {1} styles.754e83ac45b0a35831cf.css (styles) 211 kB [initial] [rendered]
20.10 chunk {2} polyfills.57838466c7d879c59877.js (polyfills) 130 bytes [initial] [rendered]
20.10 chunk {3} main.9aedd4c175d67a066c0b.js (main) 128 bytes [initial] [rendered]
20.10 
20.10 
20.10 
20.10 ERROR in node_modules/@types/jqueryui/index.d.ts(645,11): error TS1110: Type expected.
20.10 
20.14 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
20.14 npm ERR! errno 1
20.14 npm ERR! Hoge-Test@0.0.0 build: `ng build --aot --prod --base-href /priv/`
20.14 npm ERR! Exit status 1
20.14 npm ERR! 
20.14 npm ERR! Failed at the Hoge-Test@0.0.0 build script.
20.14 npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
20.15 
20.15 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
20.15 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2024-09-10T06_30_21_800Z-debug.log
------

 4 warnings found (use docker --debug to expand):
 - FromAsCasing: 'as' and 'FROM' keywords' casing do not match (line 3)
 - FromAsCasing: 'as' and 'FROM' keywords' casing do not match (line 18)
 - InvalidBaseImagePlatform: Base image alpine@sha256:3b3f647d2d99cac772ed64c4791e5d9b750dd5fe0b25db653ec4976f7b72837c was pulled with platform "linux/arm64", expected "linux/amd64" for current build (line 33)
 - InvalidBaseImagePlatform: Base image arm64v8/erlang@sha256:a9832017735f81c862faeb36ec84faeda2e12dbc3e2faf351eb381736f7e717b was pulled with platform "linux/arm64", expected "linux/amd64" for current build (line 18)
Hoge.Dockerfile:12
--------------------
  10 |     RUN npm install -g npm@6.13.7
  11 |     RUN npm install ng-circle-progress@1.5.1 --save
  12 | >>> RUN npm run build
  13 |     
  14 |     # Get Arm based Docker Alpine Linux, including Erlang/OTP 20,
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm run build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

package.jsonは以下の内容です。
{
  "name": "Hoge-Test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --port 8085 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --host=localhost",
    "build": "ng build --aot --prod --base-href /priv/",
    "prebuild": "ts-node git.version.ts",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^2.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "9.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "4.0.0",
    "@types/file-saver": "^1.3.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.9",
    "@types/jqueryui": "^1.12.4",
    "angular-2-local-storage": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "buffer": "^5.2.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.8",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "iconv-cp932": "^1.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jqueryui": "^1.11.1",
    "js-base64": "^2.5.1",
    "ng-circle-progress": "^1.2.0",
    "ng2-directory-tree": "^0.4.0",
    "ng2-right-click-menu": "^1.0.1",
    "ngx-modal": "0.0.29",
    "ngx-toastr": "^9.0.2",
    "parse-listing-ftp": "^1.1.3",
    "rxjs": "6.2.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.2.1",
    "validate-ip-node": "^1.0.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}

dockerファイルは以下の内容です。
FROM node:10.16.3-stretch@sha256:f4b6f471cdd4b66b27eef899e7f8423ecd9fbfc863b2cb7a59978a7f64c8e0c3 as build-front
WORKDIR /usr/src/hoge
COPY .git ./.git
COPY front-end ./front-end
WORKDIR /usr/src/hoge/front-end
RUN apt-get install -y git
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g npm@6.13.7
RUN npm install ng-circle-progress@1.5.1 --save
RUN npm run build


今回の問題について解決しました。
package.json内のパッケージのバージョン指定に問題がありました。
2年経ってパッケージのバージョンが更新されたことにより発生したようです。
以下のバージョンを固定にすることでビルドが成功しました。
typescript: ~2.7.2 -> typescript: 2.7.2
@types/jquery: ^3.3.9 -> @types/jquery: 3.3.9
@types/jqueryui: ^1.12.4 -> @types/jqueryui: 1.12.4
